# "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

Tags: iis-7, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a web application built in VS 2012 on IIS7. Getting the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

I have checked, I have this DLL in the following locations -

1 - My project location bin directory
2 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

But I find that the DLLs are of different size at different places, at one place it is 1.53 MB where as other is 1.68 MB.

This machine is 64 bit. And I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server 2008 Express Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the answer for this problem. It started working as soon as I replaced the replication dll in my bin folder. The problem was with the version of this DLL.